# Why is postgres container ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* in Gitlab CI

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab CI keeps ignoring the sql-files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` in [this project](https://gitlab.com/mcnesium/docker-entrypoint-initdb-test).

here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  testdb:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: lbsn-testdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "65432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

here is `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: debian:stable-slim
  script:
    - bash ./deploy.sh
```

The deployment script basically uses rsync to deploy the content of the repository to to the server via SSH:

```
rsync -rav --chmod=Du+rwx,Dgo-rwx,u+rw,go-rw -e "ssh -l gitlab-ci" --exclude=".git" --delete ./ "gitlab-ci@$DEPLOY_SERVER:test/"
```

and then ssh's into the server to stop and restart the container:

```
ssh "gitlab-ci@$DEPLOY_SERVER" "cd test && docker-compose down && docker-compose up --build --detach"
```

This all [goes well](https://gitlab.com/mcnesium/docker-entrypoint-initdb-test/-/jobs/209776868), but when the container starts up, it is supposed to run all the files that are in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` as we can see [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L145-L163).

But instead, when doing `docker logs -f lbsn-testdb` on the server, I can see it stating

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

and I have no clue, why that happens. When running this container locally or even when I ssh to that server, clone the repo and bring up the containers manually, it all goes well and parses the sql-files. Just not when the Gitlab CI does it.

Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: Weird, but here's my shot in the dark: [This line](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e5215260f0c76356c12c385e21bfe1bd4f8a6dd2/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L160) indicates that there doesn't seem to be any file that could be run. Could you add something like `docker exec your_db_container ls -l /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` to your CI config, just to make sure that the SQL file is really there?

Comment: yes it is really there

Comment: Did you check whether there are still volumes around by running `docker volume ls`? If so, try to delete them (if there is nothing important there, of course – if this is the case, just rename the service in the `docker-compose.yml`). If this helps, try to change `docker-compose down` in your script to `docker-compose down -v`.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason why you've added `--build` to your command? You didn't specify any build part in your `docker-compose.yml`, so...

Comment: sorry, the `--build` parameter was a leftover from breaking this down to a minimal example. But it's not that what went wrong, but something really stupid, see my own answer.

Comment: So one note is that your file extension should be `.sql` not anything else such as `.ddl`. Check out the link @bellackn sent to see why.

Comment: bellackn gave good advice. `docker exec your_db_container ls -l /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` showed me the dir was empty- I forgot I had moved its location in my repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been easier than I expected, and fatally nothing to do with Gitlab CI but with file permissions.

I passed `--chmod=Du+rwx,Dgo-rwx,u+rw,go-rw` to `rsync` which looked really secure because only the user can do stuff. I confess that I propably copypasted it from somewhere on the internet. But then the files are mounted to the Docker container, and in there they have those permissions as well:

```
-rw------- 1 1005 1004 314 May  8 15:48 100-create-database.sql
```

On the host my gitlab-ci user owns those files, they are obviously also owned by some user with ID 1005 in the container as well, and no permissions are given to other users than this one.

Inside the container the user who does things is `postgres` though, but it can't read those files. Instead of complaining about that, it just ignores them. That might be something to create an issue about…

[Now that I pass](https://gitlab.com/mcnesium/docker-entrypoint-initdb-test/commit/134814594249b14c01e513a5361a2d9d66ec9a4f) `--chmod=D755,F644` it looks like that:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 1005 1004  314 May  8 15:48 100-create-database.sql
```

and the docker logs say

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/100-create-database.sql
```

Too easy to think of in the first place :-/

Answer (score 5):

If you already run the postgres service before, the init files will be ignored when you restart it so try to use `--build` to build the image again

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

and before you run again :

Check the existing volumes with

```
docker volume ls
```

Then remove the one that you are using for you pg service with

```
docker volume rm {volume_name}
```

-> Make sure that the volume is not used by a container, if so then remove the container as well

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic discovering a similar problem with PostgreSQL installation using the docker-compose tool.

The solution is basically the same. For the provided configuration:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  testdb:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: lbsn-testdb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "65432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Your deployment script should set 0755 permissions to your postgres container volume, like `chmod -R 0755 ./testdb` in this case. It is important to make all subdirectories visible, so `chmod -R` option is required.

Official Postgres image is running under internal postgres user with the UID 70. Your application user in the host is most likely has different UID like 1000 or something similar. That is the reason for postgres init script to miss installation steps due to permissions error. This issue appears several years, but still exist in the latest PostgreSQL version (currently is 12.1)

Please be aware of security vulnerability when having readable for all init files in the system. It is good to use shell environment variables to pass secrets into the init scrip.

Here is a docker-compose example:

```
 postgres:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    container_name: app-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - APP_POSTGRES_DB
      - APP_POSTGRES_SCHEMA
      - APP_POSTGRES_USER
      - APP_POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - $HOME/app/conf/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - $HOME/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Corresponding script `create-users.sh` for creating users may looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

POSTGRES_USER="${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
APP_POSTGRES_DB="${APP_POSTGRES_DB:-app}"
APP_POSTGRES_SCHEMA="${APP_POSTGRES_SCHEMA:-app}"
APP_POSTGRES_USER="${APP_POSTGRES_USER:-appuser}"
APP_POSTGRES_PASSWORD="${APP_POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-app}"

DATABASE="${APP_POSTGRES_DB}"

# Create single database.
psql --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" --command "CREATE DATABASE ${DATABASE}"

# Create app user.
psql --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" --command "CREATE USER ${APP_POSTGRES_USER} SUPERUSER PASSWORD '${APP_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}'"
psql --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" --command "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${DATABASE} TO ${APP_POSTGRES_USER}"
psql --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" --dbname "${DATABASE}" --command "CREATE SCHEMA ${APP_POSTGRES_SCHEMA} AUTHORIZATION ${APP_POSTGRES_USER}"
psql --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "${POSTGRES_USER}" --command "ALTER USER ${APP_POSTGRES_USER} SET search_path = ${APP_POSTGRES_SCHEMA},public"
```